# Are there any viable alternatives to linear mixed models when the independent (predictive) variable lacks follow-up data?

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models, panel-data, predictor

I am attempting to conduct a longitudinal analysis on a dataset with one independent variable and five dependent variables. **We aim to determine whether the independent variable can predict changes in the dependents**. However, the independent variable is only measured once at the baseline.

Is it possible to use the linear mixed model in such a situation?
If not, I wonder if there are any other options besides linear mixed models for this analysis.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you may have.

New edit:
Based on the comments, I used mixed models in SPSS and JMP, but the results from both software had the same problem:
As previously mentioned, unlike my dependent variables, my independent variable was not followed for the second visit of patients.
**When the mixed model analysis was performed, both softwares completely ignored 2nd visit values for all the variables. So they analyze the first visit only.**
I used different covariate structures and procedures available in those softwares, but none of them changed this issue in results.
I'd like to know if it's only possible in R or a similar programming language, or if I'm doing something wrong.
Something that came to my mind is that maybe I should handle the independent variable missing data similar to a variable such as gender, which remains the same for both time points. That is, to copy each patient's value in the first visit and paste it into the second visit of the same patient. Currently, I have defined all "Iv" values of the second visit as missing.

My data is sorted in long format, and missing values are defined as such.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes this can work.  Just be sure that it meets your ultimate goal.  It meets the goal of seeing whether time zero information is associated wiith longitudinal trajectory.  And beware of mixed models not fitted the correlation patterns over time - see [this](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Comment: An LMM does not require independent variables that are measured repeatedly. There may be other reasons not to use one (see @FrankHarrell 's comment, for some) but this isn't one.

Comment: Dear @FrankHarrell, thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Dear @FrankHarrell,

I want to express my gratitude for your guidance in the past. However, I regret to inform you that I have encountered another problem during my analysis that I have been unable to solve. Would you be so kind as to review the question and the additional part I have included?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: It seems pretty likely that you are doing something wrong; I don't know SPSS at all, so I can't even guess what might be going on.

Comment: Dear @PeterFlom,
Thank you for your guidance. Could you please suggest any possible errors that could cause this problem? As you mentioned, you are unfamiliar with SPSS or JMP, so if you can explain it in the context of Rstudio, I will try to match it with the procedures in the software.
Thank you in advance for your guidance. Best regards.

Comment: I think it's probably some kind of error in your code.

Comment: Dear @PeterFlom,
Thank you for your assistance and for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately, spss and jmp are GUI-based software; hence, no coding is involved.

Comment: The GUI generates code. Do those softwares not let you see it?  I don't like GUI statistics, though.   I wrote a Medium blog post about this: https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/how-user-friendly-should-statistical-software-be-92278a8357c6?sk=0e8cb4504f8895f4d9e3e26fe621515d